# How can I display the count with this function?

Tags: mysql, count

So this generates 21 rows of data, but I want it to show the actual count of 21. Any thoughts/suggestions?

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT left join VENDOR ON PRODUCT.V_CODE = VENDOR.V_CODE 
UNION
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT RIGHT JOIN VENDOR ON PRODUCT.V_CODE = VENDOR.V_CODE;
```

Comment: this outputs something different (higher) because i have a union function with two separate join functions within it

Comment: In that case you've mis-characterised the problem. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the counts per select.

```
SELECT SUM(c) FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM PRODUCT left join VENDOR ON PRODUCT.V_CODE = VENDOR.V_CODE 
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRODUCT RIGHT JOIN VENDOR ON PRODUCT.V_CODE = VENDOR.V_CODE;
);
```

Comment: This returns 35 because it adds the the sum of the both (21) and then another 14 from the second query. I've been playing with this for so long and cant figure out how to just count the rows that the function itself outputs